# DataFlavors between 2 JTrees (Java)

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop, jtree

Could anyone help me allow a DataFlavor from one tree into the other? I have been following a few tutorials, and have a drag and drop working within the two trees, however I would like to be able to drag between them.

This is the part that is throwing the exception, within my overridden importData method;

```
try {  
        Transferable t = support.getTransferable();  
        nodes = (MyNode[])t.getTransferData(nodesFlavor);  
} catch(UnsupportedFlavorException ufe) {  
        System.out.println("UnsupportedFlavor: " + ufe.getMessage());  
} catch(java.io.IOException ioe) {  
        System.out.println("I/O error: " + ioe.getMessage());  
}
```

The exception thrown is;

UnsupportedFlavor: application/x-java-jvm-local-objectref

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,

Shaun

Comment: Can you modify the code so it outputs a stack trace on `UnsupportedFlavorException` and post the trace?

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement a custom `TransferHandler`. From [the java tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/transferhandler.html),

> List, table, and tree do not support drop by default. The reason for
>   this is that there is no all-purpose way to handle a drop on these
>   components. ... While Swing cannot provide a default implementation
>   for these components, the framework for drop is there. You need only
>   to provide a custom TransferHandler that manages the actual import of
>   data."

If you are exporting just the names of the tree nodes as strings, this should be pretty easy. See the rest of that tutorial for info on how to do this. If you are trying to export an object, you will need to create your own `Transferable` implementation too.

Comment: I have my own TransferHandler class, and the drag and drop is working fine within each tree. The problem comes when I try to drag a node from one tree to the other. The data flavors are not premitted, even though they are both different instances of the same class.